# Music Player Data Structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am making a music player for fun, and have run into a issue thinking about how to structure the data. My first thought was a tree structure where Genre was the root and each genre holds a list of artists, each artist holds a list of albums, each album holds a list of song titles. The problem with this is that albums get split up because some songs on an album have a genre of "rock" and another song on the same album might have a genre called "metal".

Any thoughts on a better approach?

Comment: think database... then you can sort as you please, later on...

Comment: For some reason the thought of using a database never even really crossed my mind, thanks, that should definitely work.

Comment: btw -- its not necessarily a "real, full on database" though, heck, in-memory sql-lite and stuff is great these days. But flattening the list, one way or another. :-)

Comment: I think keeping all of the info out of memory might be for the best, when you are dealing with 10,000+ songs for some people.  Also, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is that almost everyone has a different way of categorizing music so you might want to make the display format flexible.

A popular option is to 'import' music into a 'library' which is basically just scanning a user defined directory for supported formats, ripping out as much information as you can from each file and importing into an internal database.

Most players then let you select to display music by Album, Genre, Artist, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I got that part already, I was more worried about once I had all of the information, how to structure it to be able to sort and search in logn time.  But david van brink had a good idea in the comment to my OP, think that should solve it.

Thank you for taking the time to help me!